# Opening data file via contextual menu crashes app before my code begins

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I don't even know how to debug this one. This app, developed using MFC in Visual Studio, has worked well for many years but I got a customer report that it was crashing when a data file was being opened in Windows by right-clicking on the file in Explorer and selecting "Open with...". The customer also reports that a crash ensues whenever he tries to open a file from within Outlook.

I checked, and sure enough, that does happen consistently. I consistently get a crash with the message "An unhandled Win32 exception occurred in MyApp.exe [*nnnn*]." *nnnn* is a 4-digit number, not always the same. The most recent value it had was 2322. I then choose to debug with Visual Studio 2010, and next I get an alert "Unhandled exception at 0x00c72cf3 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." The debugger shows the break location as being inside `_heap_alloc(size)`, which was called from `_malloc_base(size)` with a reasonable value of `size` (around 6500000 usually).

The debugger shows me that the code is in `msvcr100.dll!malloc(size)` but provides no further useful information about the call stack. I've tried setting the next execution location, thinking I might step out to see where it goes, but I first get a message that I will have the wrong stack frame and be in a different function. Pressing onward and trying to step out of `_malloc_base()` I quickly run into a situation where the debugger tells me the source isn't available.

I've peppered my code with log messages, none of which are ever encountered. As nearly as I can tell, the crash is happening somewhere within `__DllMainCRTStartup()` long before execution even reaches `MyApp::InitInstance()` where my code begins.

The digging I've done so far suggested that I should run `sfc/scannow` at a command propmt, using Admin privileges, to scan for corruption in the system. I did that, and got back a "no problem" report.

I've done most of my testing on Windows 7 Ultimate (32 bit), but the problem happens consistently on Windows 10 as well.

The app works well when files are opened via either the File menu or by drag-and-drop.

Given that the crash seems to be happening in the Microsoft-provided app startup code, I am currently at a loss as how to even proceed to further debug or fix the problem.

Everything works fine when I drag a data file onto the app icon. I had thought that that would trigger the same sequence of events that right-clicking on the data and selecting the app via "Open With.." would do, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

---

I'd like to start the app in the debugger and give it the same initial data it would get if I launched it via the contextual menu, but I have no idea how to do that.

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: I would recommend looking into a difference in the working directory. For example, a normal app start probably has a working directory of wherever the `.exe` is located, but I bet an Open With uses something else, such as the Windows directory or the directory of the opened file.

Comment: The reason I believe the working directory may be important is that it can participate in the DLL loading process and I would bet that you're getting an incompatible version of one or more DLLs you depend on. [DLL search order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications)

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thanks, I'll see if I can find out anything about that.

Comment: In `Configuration Properties`, `Command Arguments`, try putting the full path to that file and see if it crashes (use quotes). I believe it would be the same as `Open With`